# Shopify template ''if tage was never closed'

Tags: layout, themes, shopify, liquid

Trying to get liquid to add the class has_second_image if there is a 2nd image present but when I run yarn start the terminal spits out 'if tag was never closed"

```
  {% liquid 
   assign has_second_image = false
  
    if product.images[1]
     assign has_second_image = true
    endif 
  %}

<a  href="{{ product.url }}" class="product-tile{% if has_second_image %} product-tile-has-second-image{% endif %}">
  <div class="product-tile_image-wrapper"{% if has_second_image %} style= "background-image: url({{ product.images[1] | img_url: '700x' }});">
    <img class="product-tile_image" src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '700x' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-tile_info">
    <h3 class="product-tile_title"> {{ product.title }}</h3>
    <span class="product-tile_price">{{ product.price | money }}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close your if statement on line 10 of the code you posted:

```
<div class="product-tile_image-wrapper"{% if has_second_image %} style= "background-image: url({{ product.images[1] | img_url: '700x' }});">
```

This should fix it:

```
<div class="product-tile_image-wrapper"{% if has_second_image %} style= "background-image: url({{ product.images[1] | img_url: '700x' }});"{% endif %}>
```